# Highly resistant House Plant

Tags: magic, post-apocalypse, flora

**The Premise**

My world takes place about **25 years** after an **magical** apocalyptic event killed most life in my setting. It also left the **sky permanently dark** which is caused by thick magical clouds.

Such conditions are generally really bad for plants. My problem is that i need for stylistic reasons a good number of **Potted House Plants** to have survived in a Shopping Mall.

So my question is what **specific plant species** could **survive** such in such an environment. My own idea was that maybe an **aleo vera** could survive though i am not 100 % certain it even can. So clarifying this would also help.

**Environmental Conditions**

- They are located **inside** a building.
- There is **very little** water which comes mainly from rusty pipes plus on **irrigation system**.
- Only **artificial light** is available which can be **special lamps** if needed.
- The air is **stale** and slightly **corrosive** through magic.
- The room temperature is around
  **3 - 18 °C** depending on the season.
- Any mentioned equipment **won't be maintained** for the time period.

**Requirements for the Plant**

- It should either be able **self replicate** under the described conditions.
- It has to fit into a **ceramic plant pot**.
- It must have clearly **discernible leaves**.
- It should have a notable ability to **cleanse the air** around it.

*Note: English is not my primary language so please excuse any grammar or spelling errors.*

Comment: Would it be acceptable for the plant to have released seeds, died and a new plant of the same type to have grown in each pot in a repeated cycle over the 25 years?  Also, the last point is unclear - what is "a clearly positive effect on the room's climate" given that the air is defined as stale and (somehow) slightly corrosive?

Comment: Yes the idea with the seeds is fine if it is logical. The last part is just the ability of the plant to filter toxic substances out of the air. I will edit the post soon to make it more clear. By the way do you have any idea of other tags this question could fit into as i did not have any additional ideas.

Comment: (1) [Gardening Stack Exchange](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask for advice about plants which can survive with only artificial lighting. Just be sure to formulate your question as a real-life question. (2) A Google search for low-light indoor plants will do wonders. (3) Please edit the question to explain why the stereotypical no-maintenance low-light houseplants [*Epipremnum aureum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum) aka "pothos" and [*Aspidistra elatior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspidistra_elatior) aka the "cast-iron plant" don't work.

Comment: **AlexP** thank you. This could be a consideration however ever due to the magical elements of my question i am going to leave it here for the time being.

Comment: What research have you performed? Have you visited a shopping mall to see what plants (if any) they have growing there? Shopping malls (especially if they were built 50 years ago) are already a darkened-sky artificial-light-only environments. Of course, what you might discover is that there are no living plants in a shopping mall....

Comment: **JBH** from what i know there are plants in some malls. I want them in mine in there for manly some flavour purposes and because i want to turn them into plant monsters. This happens because of the magical air in there. For the in world purposes for why they are there is because they are supposed to filter the magic out of the air.

Comment: Based on your requirements, I'd suggest that Plastic plants are probably the closest to your requirements...

Comment: While this is possible i would like them to be real plants which is why i made this question. If there are any factors which would make survival for a plant impossible let me know. Also once i have a plant that would come even close to what i need i am sure i could make the rest work via magic.

Comment: Call me **petty** (or indeed **hypocritical**, given my frequent habit of _italicizing_ text) but I feel that **bold text** in **this quantity** fails to impart **emphasis** but instead just makes stuff **harder to read**. Consider making more use of plain text.

Comment: Do you aim at creating a controlled environment when outdoor conditions don't allow this or rivaling groups may take over the crop area? In that case only, the setting would make sense. You may search for info about _grow tents_ , rainwater catchement and storage, ventillation and air circulation. Rusty pipes will not hold long enough, either. Outdoors plants would need more intensive light than what houseplants would need.

Comment: The plant should stay alive by itself as there is no one coming to help it or fix anything. Additionally it is not about farming but having some plant that can decently filter the air survive for this long.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need a mall.  Most plants will be fine at light levels about 1/3 that of sunlight.  lower canopy jungle plants do ok in 5% line.

I kept a benjamin fig in my office lower basement under office levels of fluorescent lighting.  Philodendrons will be ok.  Pothos.  Hostas.  Woods violet.  Canada buffaloberry, many ferns.  Probably creeping bell flower.  Northern bedsstraw, snowberry,  Spider plant,  hoya,

---

Your best bet for water is to have a leaky roof so that water from the roof, dumps into the mall, and spreads.  You end up with a mound with plants that need more water at the centre.  If there is a working toilet in use, that provides a bit of fertilizer.

---

You need some furious handwaving to keep the skies dark that long.  I vaguely recall the numbers that came out of the nuclear winter studies figured it would be 5-10 years before enough dust settle to grow crops.  Later studies shortened this to nuclear autumn.  wikipedia "nuclear winter" for details

Comment: Thank you. The sky is dark because of magic that blocks sunlight probably up to 80 or 90% of it. And while normally a leaking roof would be a good idea the rain in my world is due to the magic similar to oil which i am certain of is horrible for plants. That really leaves leaking by water systems or moisture as only freshwater sources. I am also a little worried about the possible ground quality which will decrease in nutritional value overtime as really there is no one providing fertilizer.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be less about the plants but rather about the place, like the mall you decribed. Plants outside trying to rely on natural sunlight almost completely died out. Just the plants inside the place who got artificial light survived on that.

So you rather need to think about what kind of place would have an artificial lighting system that continues to mostly work for 25 years without any humans around. I'm not sure whether a mall would qualify here, maybe a bunker or some military facility that was designed to be self-sufficient. The plants inside are then just random potted plants that happened to be there.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind though the mall is partially designed to keep the the plants alive its sadly not something like a bunker. So the Plants should be able to survive the conditions as described. If you have any **specific plants** in mind that could **suffice my requirements** please be so kind and **add them to your answer**. But overall thank you for your input.

Answer (score -1):

I would think - to survive in a arcade- i would go with solar/glasfiber redirected light from the sun- and hermetically bottled up eco-systems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottle_garden

It can have any shape- and within, though dwarfed by the lack of input life goes on- unaffected by radioactivity. Make the bottles futuristic (diamond) and it can survive a nuke itself, blowing all glassware out.

Add a little gardening robot to it if you want to over the top.

PS: In theory- any hermetically sealed environment can become such a bottle garden, as long energy pours into it. So if your arcade/skyscraper was sealed thoroughly, life within could be lush and completely undisturbed by the world "outside" ending. Basically everything can be a greenhouse if it remains undisturbed.

Comment: While i thank you for your input sadly there is no sun visible at all times in my world think like a thick layer of clouds that block most of the light. Also the apocalypse is not of a nuclear nature and more of a fallout of a highly corrosive substance.

Comment: LEDs with geothermal input or water-powerplants? Wind-power? Would make them also very- before - after affected. If the LED slowly dies, the bottle-garden withers away to a tree-skeletton and cannibalistic critters..

Comment: The lamps should still be able to function. As they have a working power source. What i am unsure about is if they could continuously work for 25 years considering black out do happen on a regular basis.

Comment: In theory, you could make a system of bottle gardens, where if one is dead, it gets recolonized by others. Ther are plants, that thrieve in low-light environments, such as djungels and caves (with a little light admittetly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampenflora). Or the bottle garden gets replanted, every time the power returns from dried seeds..

Comment: Ahh thanks that should prove helpful. Do you mind telling which plants can grow in such manner.

Comment: I just google low light plants and the usual suspects pop up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_floor#Tropical_forests
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratification_(vegetation)
You would go for stuff that can survive in very dense canopied rainforrests. Be aware that some plants- are not plants at all.. as in the life parasitic from surrounding trees, not photosynthesizing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152031/discussion-between-fallenspacerock-and-pica).